# Best way to make routes on mod_wsgi python

Tags: python, mod-wsgi

Currently, I am using mod_wsgi for developing python applications on server. However, application will be big, really big and my question is following:

How to make a good routing system on mod_wsgi(urls, localhost/login route and so on). Normally, I am doing that with:

```
urls = [
    (r'^$', index),
    (r'hello/?$', hello),
    (r'hello/(.+)$', hello)
]

def application(environ, start_response):
    """
    The main WSGI application. Dispatch the current request to
    the functions from above and store the regular expression
    captures in the WSGI environment as  `myapp.url_args` so that
    the functions from above can access the url placeholders.

    If nothing matches call the `not_found` function.
    """
    path = environ.get('PATH_INFO', '').lstrip('/')
    for regex, callback in urls:
        match = re.search(regex, path)
        if match is not None:
            environ['myapp.url_args'] = match.groups()
            return callback(environ, start_response)
    return not_found(environ, start_response)
```

Now, I am thinking... If I write every route there, python document will have thousands and thousands of code lines. Will it make it slow?

Don't write about frameworks because I don't like it, I want to start from scratch.

Comment: I dont think your application is architectured correctly if you need thousands of url endpoints. Either use the querystring for parameters or use a static folder for static content.

Comment: for everything is used querystring, but i need to write function for every query and that will make a big number of lines...

Comment: Cant you just put the parameters for a query in the querystring and make one generic endpoint that executes queries?

Answer (score 1):

You really don't want to do it yourself. You would be much better off using an existing WSGI component library such as Werkzeug, which has components for handling all of this. A WSGI component library such as Werkzeug is not a framework, but is the components you can use to create a framework. At least go research what Werkzeug does and learn from it, rather than take a stance that you want to do everything yourself from scratch. Other people have solved these issues before, so don't ignore what they have done and which is known to work.